# WPF path programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to draw some paths into a grid, those paths definition are stored on a database something like this:

```
    <Path x:Name="MyPath" Data="M0.073363333,7.3695667 L6.8231533,0.032799774 13.131994,0.1797551 0.073726657,14.118345 0.22044918,7.6625736 0.073726657,24.388874 8.1436304,24.45903 32.86621,0.1063924 26.116795,-0.040326216 1.1813478,24.399203 24.25612,24.559788 49.152072,0.10626289 41.963089,0.03290334 17.610519,24.513989 0.062195513,24.390331 0.078522714,24.388897 43.226538,24.706345 65.933927,2.4904153 65.952566,0.014562738 61.092016,0.087921331 36.910362,24.648632 0.075087122,24.388897 59.64313,24.791428 65.842163,18.262777&#xD;&#xA;65.842163,11.440329 53.139979,24.754434 0.078522714,24.392332" Fill="#FF2764BB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24.833" Margin="0.073,-0.04,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65.892"/>
```

It is possible to insert this path directly into my grid or need to build a custom object and then assign each propertie to my custom object?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `Data` property is a `DependencyProperty`, so couldn't you just bind `Path.Data` it to your data value from the database? If you wanted a dynamic grid as well with path items placed in it, use an `<ItemsControl>` with an `<ItemsPanelTemplate>` set to the `<Grid>`, bind the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` properties in the `<ItemContainerStyle>`, and bind the `<Path Data="{Binding PathData}" />` in the `<ItemTemplate>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Path objects in your codebehind as follows:

```
Path path = new Path()
{
   Data = dal.DataPath;
   Fill = dal.FillColumn;
   HorizontalAlignment = (System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment)dal.Hori;
   //etc.
   //you get the gist
};
```

Remember this Path inherits from Shape which is an FrameworkElement so you can populate your grid with many of them.

```
<Grid x:Name="theGrid" ></Grid>

theGrid.Children.Add(path);
```

Also you can set the row or column of your path as follows:

```
Grid.SetRow(path,0);
```

Comment: Yes thas ok, ``DataPath`` That ins't my really question, All this path properties are variable and are stored in one field on my database. I'm looking for a way to set all with one instruction.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez ok i understand, then yes it is best to create an class that will handle loading each record as a Path

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez please see an updated answer, remember from the DB you can create a model which is then accessed from the UI, this is good practice